# console.log not showing js value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am iterating through JSON data, but I am not able to get the value in `console.log`.
Can you tell me how to fix it?
I  am writing the correct syntax for my console.
I'm providing my code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Bn63/4/

```
function allProfile() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allProfile.length; i++) {
        console.log("i am here");
        console.log(allProfile[i].Class of Service 1);
    }
}

var allProfile = [{
    Profile: 101,
        'Class of Service 1': '90%'
        
}];
```

Comment: `allProfile[i].["Class of Service 1"]` ?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have use bracket notation to access that property

```
allProfile[i]['Class of Service 1']
```

and your function has the same name as the object, so it's overwritten

```
function iterator() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allProfile.length; i++) {
        console.log(allProfile[i]['Class of Service 1']);
    }
}

var allProfile = [{
    Profile: 101,
    'Class of Service 1': '90%'
}];

iterator();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7Bn63/6/)